# Why the number of CPU's so Large

Tags: windows, cpu, cpu-usage, task-manager, resource-usage

I was installing Android studio and just so that I could delete the process I had my Task manager open and Saw that the CPU number was reaching 40 somethimes.

How is this done, are multiple CPU emulated. My machine has x86 Windows Vista quad core.
[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The number you see in that column doesn't actually refer to the number of CPUs in use. If you look at [the Microsoft page that explains the column headers](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-task-manager-memory-columns-mean#1TC=windows-7) (look for the heading titled "CPU Usage"), you can see that the number actually represents:

> The percentage of time that a process used the CPU since the last update

This is the reason that the sum of all values in the CPU column never go above 100, as that would imply that the CPU is at more than 100% usage, which doesn't make sense.

In Windows 8, percentages are displayed instead of pure numbers, which clears up some of the inherent confusion.

Comment: ahh..so its percentage CPU utilization...that was naive from me...
I got confused because another process was having value 2 which i presumed as one of the processor number.

Comment: And I come from Linux background :/

Comment: @GoodGads It's a mistake I've seen others make in the past. Windows 8 is a bit clearer because it displays `12%` rather than just `12` and includes a total utilisation percentage in the header.